# Wrt "Hello World" prgrm bt wth n vwls

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, hello-world

Create A "Hello, World!" program but without any vowels. Winner is the program with the least bytes.

**Rules:**

- No vowels are allowed in the code.
- Must print to STDOUT
- Must be a full program.
- Submissions are measured in Bytes

Any language goes as long as there aren't any vowels

Edit:
Y is only a vowel if there aren't any other vowels in the same word.

Comment: Disallowing functions and requiring output to STDOUT disqualifies a lot of languages, and goes against site defaults. Are you sure you want to do that? Also, do you count `y` as a vowel?

Comment: Yeah ill edit the question to clarify the vowels and functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/53748 (Stuck, 0 bytes).

Comment: What about `ạ`,`ẹ`,`ị`,`ọ`,`ụ`,`Ạ`,`Ẹ`,`Ị`,`Ọ`,`Ụ`, etc.? Do they count as vowels or not? And `А` and `О` (Cyrillic)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Suppose so but is quite a bland answer.

Comment: @TheThonnu Since I'm basing this off English vowels, I'd say no.

Comment: Things to avoid: [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260) and [Cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260)

Comment: > Edit: Y is only a vowel if there aren't any other vowels in the same word.

So is it possible that a valid submission contains a 'Y'? If so, please give an example. If not, it's probably clearer to just say that 'Y' is a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
⍘Ｉ”)¶iτCφ(≦$χ≕G＆”γ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNdwTiwu0VAyMjIwNDQxNzG2NLEwNDA0MzG0NDcxNbUwM1TS1FFI19S0/v//v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｉ”...”     Cast compressed string `22011474394810164197455861` to integer
⍘      γ    Convert to base 95 using printable ASCII
            Implicitly print
```

Best I could do without compression was 19 bytes:

```
⭆Pmttw4(_wztl)℅⁻℅ι⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaCgF5JaUlJtoxJdXleRoKukoOAOVJiaXpBZp@GbmlRZr@BelZOYl5mhkauooWGgCgfX///91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Subtracts `8` from the ASCII codes of each character in the string constant. (Other values such as `2` can also be used.)

Answer (score 1):

Got it, MetaGolfScript-695337743287229800148806645588258 solution is 0 bytes

Comment: MetaGolfScript answers aren't considered interesting anymore

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms HQ9+ maybe?

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) / [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) (polyglots), 2 bytes

```
kH
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi7I9lhQnJRdDuTBhAA) or [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJrSCIsIiIsIiJd)

Making this a CW because it's very boring and exactly the same as the normal Hello, World! submissions in Thunno 2 and Vyxal.

Comment: To add to this, [Japt's Hello World also has no latin vowel characters](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YEjBTSwgV45sZCE&input=IjIwMTAtMDUi)

Comment: @noodleman it's a CW, edit it in if you want

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Always remember to “;ṇTry HARD</sup>

```
“;ṇṪṙẏHȦ»Ḋ
```

A full program which prints the result (also a niladic Link yielding it).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4oCcO@G5h@G5quG5meG6j0jIpsK74biK//8)**

#### How?

Without the restriction, we could have the compressed string `“3ḅaė;œ»` for \$8\$ bytes.

```
“;ṇṪṙẏHȦ»Ḋ - Main Link: no arguments
“;ṇṪṙẏHȦ»  - compressed string = "\nHello, World!"
         Ḋ - dequeue -> "Hello, World!"
           - implicit print
```

---

##### Other \$10\$ byters

(...with nothing that could be considered a vowel, like `Ȧ`)

```
“¿ṃ{+ṀH“£» - Main Link: no arguments
“......“.» - list of compressed strings:
 ¿ṃ{+ṀH    -   "Hello, World"
        £  -   "!"
             -> ["Hello, World", "!"]
           - implicit, smashing print
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xD@x/ubK7WfrizwQPEW3xo9///AA)

```
“Ṣc çsṢƑ»Ṗ - Main Link: no arguments
“Ṣc çsṢƑ»  - compressed string = "Hello, World!$"
         Ṗ - pop -> "Hello, World!"
           - implicit print
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHOxclKxxeXgykj008tPvhzmn//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 21 bytes

```
K`H1ll3, W3rld!
T`d`v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zvBwzAnx1hHIdy4KCdFkSskISWh7P9/AA) Explanation:

```
K`H1ll3, W3rld!
```

Start with the string constant `H1ll3, W3rld!`.

```
T`d`v
```

Change `1` to `e` and `3` to `o`.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 19 bytes

```
'Gdkkn+Vnqkc '{)}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X909JTs7T1s@LK8wO1lBvVqzVvX/fwA)

```
'Gdkkn+Vnqkc '      Hello world but -1 applied to each character
               {)}%  Add back 1 to each character
```

Answer (score 0):

## NASM (linux x32), 66 bytes

The source code in hexadecimal

```
64 62 22 04 04 43 E8 0E 22 2C 30 2C 30 2C 30 2C 37 32 2C 31 30 31 2C 22 6C 6C 22 2C 31 31 31 2C 22 2C 20 57 22 2C 31 31 31 2C 22 72 6C 64 21 22 2C 31 30 2C 22 5A B1 0E 87 D1 CD 80 B0 01 4B CD 80 22
```

Printed out it looks like this:

```
db"C�",0,0,0,72,101,"ll",111,", W",111,"rld!",10,"Z�K̀"
```

This basically encodes the following assembly:

```
add al, 4
inc ebx
call _f
data db "Hello, World!", 10
_f:
pop edx
mov cl, 14
xchg edx, ecx
int 0x80
mov al, 1
dec ebx
int 0x80
```

The instruction pointer is used to make the code position independent. Unfortunately `pop ecx` corresponds to the character `Y`, so I had to add an exchange.

To compile, run

```
nasm -f elf32 golf.S -o golf.o
ld -m elf_i386 -o golf.out golf.o
./golf.out
```

where `golf.S` contains the source code

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 (or 23) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
”Ÿ™,‚ï!
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcozsetSzSedQw6/B6xf//AQ)

If we want to get rid of vowels like `Ÿ` and `ï` as well, it would be **23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** (most likely golfable some more, though..):

```
'H.•7¤p³mƶG•¦#`™„, s'!J
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3UPvUcMi80NLCg5tzj22zR3IObRMOeFRy6JHDfN0FIrVFb3@/wcA)

**Explanation:**

```python
”Ÿ™,‚ï!            # Push dictionary string "Hello, World!"
                   # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
'H                '# Push "H"
                   #  STACK: "H"
.•7¤p³mƶG•         # Push compressed string "jello world"
                   #  STACK: "H","jello world"
          ¦        # Remove the first letter: "ello world"
                   #  STACK: "H","ello world"
           #       # Split it on spaces: ["ello","world"]
                   #  STACK: "H",["ello","world"]
            `      # Pop and push both separated to the stack
                   #  STACK: "H","ello","world"
™                  # Titlecase the top word: "World"
                   #  STACK: "H","ello","World"
„,                 # Push string ", "
                   #  STACK: "H","ello","World",", "
   s               # Swap it with "World" on the stack
                   #  STACK: "H","ello",", ","World"
'!                '# Push "!"
                   #  STACK: "H","ello",", ","World","!"
J                  # Join all strings on the stack together
                   #  STACK: "Hello, World!"
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`HÁM, Wld!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YEjBTSwgV45sZCE&input=Cg)

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 48 bytes

```
=d#"H"$101›#"ll"+10›-67›#" W"+67›#"rld"-78›
```

i <3 character codes